# Set a default timezone in a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, tzinfo

I am trying to set a default, or ideally first show a predefined list of options, timezone in a form when creating a company.

Currently, the code below renders an entire list of available timezones, and finding a specific timezone is rather tedious. All of the current companies are either in one of two timezones, and it would be a better experience to default to a specific timezone, or even better, append two timezones values to the top of the list. Here is the form field:

```
= form.select :time_zone, (TZInfo::Timezone.all.map { |tz| ["(UTC #{tz.current_period.offset.utc_offset/3600}) #{tz.to_s}", tz.name] })
```

I've tried to set a few different options but there doesn't seem to be a conventional way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this API document is what you need.

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

```
form.select :time_zone, options_for_select(TZInfo::Timezone.all.map { |tz| ["(UTC #{tz.current_period.offset.utc_offset/3600}) #{tz.to_s}", tz.name] }, selected: "your default option")
```

Comment: Thanks @tsao, that works by adding a timezone (Canada/Eastern) into the selected: param. Next I wonder how you could append two options at the top of the list, followed by the remaining options. i.e Two Canadian Timezones at the top followed by the remaining timezones

Comment: @VegaStudios, the API document says "selected may also be an array of values to be selected when using a multiple select", so maybe you can set selected value be an Array.